# Does linear independence require one or two nontrivial constants?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vectors

So I've been following Paul's Notes on Differential Equations. In Section 3-7  *More on the Wronskian* he says "if the functions are linearly dependent then we can write at least one of them in terms of the other functions."
$$\begin{align*}{c_1}{f_1}\left( x \right) + {c_2}{f_2}\left( x \right) +  \cdots  + {c_n}{f_n}\left( x \right) & = 0\\  {c_1}{f_1}\left( x \right) & =  - \left( {{c_2}{f_2}\left( x \right) +  \cdots  + {c_n}{f_n}\left( x \right)} \right)\\ {f_1}\left( x \right) & =  - \frac{1}{{{c_1}}}\left( {{c_2}{f_2}\left( x \right) +  \cdots  + {c_n}{f_n}\left( x \right)} \right)\end{align*}$$
This seems to suggest that there must be at least two nontrivial constants, $c_1$ for realness, and $c_i$, where ${1<i\leq n}$, to avoid nontriviality.
The Wikipedia page for Linear Independence along with most other sources I've found claim that any set of vectors including the zero vector $\overrightarrow0$ are necessarily linearly dependent. But this would require that $\forall c_i$ where $1<i\leq n, c_i=0$, which would involve only one nonzero constant, $c_1$. Is this by definition or is my reading of Paul's Notes incorrect?

Links for Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Wronskian.aspx

Comment: You only need one constant.  In the collection $\{\vec v, \vec 0\}$, we have $\vec 0=0\times \vec v$ (Where, here, $\times$ denotes scalar multiplication.

Comment: You don'tneed to "avoid nontriviality". You can h ave $f_1$ be the zero function, which would make the collection necessarily linearly dependent. Your assertion in the second paragraph is incorrect, but irrelevant (for example, $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(2,0)$ are linearly dependent, and you don't need all but one coefficient equal to zero). Note that the "nontriviality" in the definition of linear dependence refers not to the coefficients in the expression for $f_1$, but in the coefficients in the expression for the zero function that you started with.